# SQL Server 2012 - Deadlock happening daily

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, dbcc, maxdop

We have a performance issue with a 3rd-Party application using SQL Server 2012: deadlock happen at least 10 times an hour.

The server is virtual server on VMWare 5.5 with PVSCSI adapter in persisted mode for SQL Server disks, 4 vCPU (that are seen by SQL Server as 2 CPU with 2 cores). 
It runs Windows Server 2012.

As we already had the issue, our supplier asked to set MAXDOP to 1 as they experienced problems with parallelism. It didn't solve the situation.

I ran the DBCC TRACEON (1222, -1) to get extended informations about deadlocks and transmit it to the supplier.

**Edit: Example deadlock graph**
[image]

In XML Format: (I was not able to add it to the post)
[XML Format](http://pastebin.com/dnNw1QjJ)

**Edit2: Index Maintenance**

The following Job runs Ola Hallengren MaintenanceSolution (IndexOptimize) :

```
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d SAIDBA -Q "EXECUTE maintenance.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @FragmentationLow = NULL, @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',  @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',@FragmentationLevel1 = 3,@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y',@LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

**Edit 3: update on the situation**

I did some mining on the error log to get an overview of the time line for deadlock occurrences. It happened three to four times more frequently after a software update (120 per day), but there were already 30-40 per day previously.

As the application supplier doubts about our indexing strategy, he wants us to do it.. We will rebuild **all** the indices..
We will see if it has positive effects...

What else can I do to investigate/troubleshoot/Reduce the number of deadlocks ?

**Short answer**

1. Check ERRORLOG for deadlock frequency (is it regular or very new ?)
2. Ensure Index Maintenance exists and has run successfully.
3. Setup a trace either with SQL Server Profiler, an Extended Events solution or via Trace Flag 1222.
4. Analyze the results of the trace:

   - What queries were involved ?
   - Which tables/indices are accessed when it happens and how frequently ?

Anything else ?

Comment: You must know the apps that's produces deadlocks. There are [several issues to see how the apps works](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2014/tips-avoiding-deadlocks-sql-server/)

Comment: The application is 3rd-Party. We don't have the code and can't change it easily... We only can do service requests to suppliers... but we then need to be precise...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be anything to do with DBCC or Ola's scripts. The select query in `SP_GRPVIEW_LOAD` is deadlocking with an Update query in      `sp_regvisit_save` - `UPDATE appointment SET    ap_is_current = 0  WHERE  ap_id = @vlngCurApId`

Comment: Check the execution plans of the queries involved in the deadlocks for index and query tuning opportunities.  The likelihood of deadlocks increases when more data than needed is touched.

Answer (score -2):

Deadlocks are "simply" application logic errors. In SQL Server I think you can do the following:

- review the application logic;
- You can use transaction isolation in snapshot mode [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

See also:

[How to Track Down Deadlocks Using SQL Server 2005 Profiler](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/)

written by Brad McGehee. I think that he is more authoritative than me. He states:

> ...Deadlocks have been the bane of many a DBA. While rare for a well-designed and written application, deadlocks can be a major problem for—how can I say this delicately?—“less efficient” application code. What is even more frustrating is there is not much the DBA can to do prevent deadlocks, as the burden of preventing them in the first place is on the developers of the application...."

Comment: Giova actually you explained in general way what can be cause of deadlock but that is definitely not the answer to OP's question. I hope you would agree on that. You also suggested to change isolation level which might not be required always as a fact lot of deadlocks can eaisly be resolved with proper index and logic. The downvote says that`your post does not answers the question` it has no more significance

Comment: @Shanky: My comment asnwer the question: review the application logic. A dba tipically can't solve deadlock problems. Especially if deadlock are generated by a third party application. Actually this question can not be answered. Stop. You can mitigate this problem with indexes (not so frequent beacuse of locking behaviour) or with a different isolation level. But you can not solve this kind of errors without modifying the application logic.